# Is INTEL-SA-00075 Detection and Mitigation Tool enough to mitigate IntelME attacks

Tags: hardware, backdoor, cve, firmware, architecture

Is that tool enough to mitigate/protect againts IntelME vulnerability? 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26755?v=t

If it's not enough I more I can do to protect againts IntelME attacks ?

Answer (score 1):

No, as the link you yourself posted says (for both versions):

> This version does not provide automated mitigation support.

---

For reference, we are talking about [CVE-2017-5689](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-5689).

Intel released a statement [here](https://security-center.intel.com/advisory.aspx?intelid=INTEL-SA-00075&languageid=en-fr):

> Step 1: [Determine if you have an Intel® AMT, Intel® SBA, or Intel® ISM capable system](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-5693).  If you determine that you do not have an Intel® AMT, Intel® SBA, or Intel® ISM capable system then no further action is required.
>
> Step 2: Utilize the [INTEL-SA-00075 Detection Guide](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26755) to assess if your system has the impacted firmware. If you do have a version in the “Resolved Firmware” column no further action is required to secure your system from this vulnerability.
>
> - Linux users may alternately use the following tools and documentation.  Note: Validation is ongoing and may result in updates to this release.
> - [INTEL-SA-00075 Linux Discovery Tool and Mitigation Tools v1.0.zip](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26799/INTEL-SA-00075-Linux-Detection-and-Mitigation-Tools?wapkw=intel-sa-00075)
>
> Step 3: Intel highly recommends checking with your system OEM for updated firmware.  Firmware versions that resolve the issue have a four digit build number that starts with a “3” (X.X.XX.3XXX) Ex: 8.1.71.3608.
>
> Step 4: If a firmware update is not available from your OEM, mitigations are provided the [INTEL-SA-00075 Mitigation Guide](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26754).

TL;DR:

You can check if your system is vulnerable by running the tool you have linked in your question. If your system is vulnerable, update the firmware.